# Angular: some problems with ngrx/effects

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

I have defined an effect like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class SearchEffects {
  constructor(
    private actions$: Actions,
    private service: IService,
    private store: Store<AppState>,
  ) { }


  @Effect()
  save$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(ActionTypes.SAVE),
    withLatestFrom(this.store.select(selectors.getAllResults)),
    map(([_, results]) => results),
    switchMap(results=> {
      const observables: Array<Observable<Object>> = [];
      for (const v of results) {
        if (!v.name) {
          this.store.dispatch(new NameRequiredAction());             // if name is empty,dispatch an action,and continue naxt loop;
          continue;
        }
        const ob = this.service.save(v);
        observables.push(ob);
      }
      return merge(...observables);                 // merge all saved results.
    }),
    map(res => new SaveSuccess(res))
  );
}
```

in this effect, I got an array of object to save. And I have to save it one by one.

First,use `withLatestFrom` to get all results from ngrx/store.  as `results`

second, in `switchMap`, for...of the `results`, and save every single result. Then merge all the returned value. But if the name is empty,I should dispatch an action to notify the client and continue next loop.

third, dispatch new Action for every returned value.

I'm not sure if it's the right way to do what I want. And I don't know if it's right to dispatch and return new action in effects. Anyone helps me pls.

Comment: Are you experiencing a problem or asking for advice?

Comment: @Spiderman, I wanna know that if it is normal to both dispatch and return new action in one effect. and what is the right way to do in my situation